# How do I pass multiple parameters to a sqlite IN clause and protect against SQL injection?

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I'm using [The Microsoft.Data.Sqlite library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases#sqlite-library) relevant sqlite APIs in UWP project.

I found that if I use `IN` condition in my parameterized SQL statement, it doesn't return the correct result.

For example, if the SQL statement looks like the following:

```
sqliteCommand.CommandText = @"delete from [test_table] where col1 in(@para1,@para2)";
sqliteCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@para1", '1'));
sqliteCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@para2", '2'));
sqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It would not delete the rows when the 'col1' is '1' or '2'.

If I change the SQL to this:

```
sqliteCommand.CommandText = @"delete from [test_table] where col1 in(@para1,@para2)";
sqliteCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@para1", "1"));   
sqliteCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@para2", "2"));
```

It did work.

If I change the SQL to this:

```
sqliteCommand.CommandText = @"delete from [test_table] where col1 in ('1', '2')";
sqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

With this, it also did work.

But, if I change the SQL to this:

```
delete from [test_table] where col1 in(@para1)   
sqliteCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@para1", "'1','2'"));
//or sqliteCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@para1", "1,2"));
```

In this case, it did not work.

I think Microsoft needs to investigate this issue.

The version of 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite' library is 2.2.6.

The following is the whole code demo:

```
SqliteConnection sqliteConnection = new SqliteConnection("Filename=test.db");
sqliteConnection.Open();

SqliteDataReader sqliteDataReader;

string sql = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [test_table] ( col1 VARCHAR(1), col2 VARCHAR(1), col3 VARCHAR(4));";

SqliteCommand sqliteCommand = new SqliteCommand(sql, sqliteConnection);
sqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

sql = @"INSERT INTO [test_table] (col1, col2, col3) VALUES('1', '1', '0001')";
sqliteCommand.CommandText = sql;

sqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

sql = @"INSERT INTO [test_table] (col1, col2, col3) VALUES('2', '2', '0002')";
sqliteCommand.CommandText = sql;
sqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

sql = @"INSERT INTO [test_table] (col1, col2, col3) VALUES('3', '3', '0003')";
sqliteCommand.CommandText = sql;
sqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

sqliteCommand.CommandText = @"delete from [test_table] where col1 in(@para1,@para2)";

//sqliteCommand.CommandText = @"delete from [test_table] where col1 in('1','2')";

sqliteCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@para1", '1'));
sqliteCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@para2", '2'));

sqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

sqliteCommand.CommandText = @"select * from [test_table]";
sqliteDataReader = sqliteCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: What is the type of `col1` in your SQLite table?

Comment: '1' is different in SQL (string) vs C# (char). Can you please try using `"` instead? `("@para1", "1"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Direct Answer**

To allow deleting of variable number of entries using IN, use this code:

```
// Example data
var valuesToDelete = new List<string> { "1", "2", "4" };

sqliteCommand.CommandText = @"delete from [test_table] where col1 in(" + string.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(0, valuesToDelete.Count).Select(z => "@para" + z)) + ")";

for (var i = 0; i < valuesToDelete.Count; i++)
{
    sqliteCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@para" + i, valuesToDelete[i]));
}

sqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

`string.Join` is used to setup the right number of parameters in the SQL, and the `for` loop is designed to populate those parameters. This allows multiple values to be used inside the `IN`, and is safe from SQL Injection.

**Background**

The reason why:

```
sqliteCommand.CommandText = @"delete from [test_table] where col1 in(@para1,@para2)";
sqliteCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@para1", "1"));
sqliteCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@para2", "2"));
sqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

works but:

```
sqliteCommand.CommandText = @"delete from [test_table] where col1 in(@para1,@para2)";
sqliteCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@para1", '1'));
sqliteCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter("@para2", '2'));
sqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

doesn't is that with the latter you accidentally passed in the parameters as `char` instead of `string`.

The latter can *feel* correct, since `'` works fine in SQL normally. But SQL and C# are different - `'` can be used around a string in SQL, but not in C# (C# uses `'` for `char` and `"` for `string).

**As such, when passing string parameters in - be sure to pass them as `string` (using `"`) rather than `char`.**